# How do i extract all http links from html file using htamlagilitypack and then extract http links between tags?

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

Im trying this code :

```
private void htmlparsing(string htmlfile)
        {
            List<string> test = new List<string>();
            HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
            doc.Load(htmlfile);
            foreach (HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]"))
            {
                HtmlAttribute att = link.Attributes["href"];
                test.Add(att.Value);  
            }
            doc.Save(@"d:\file.htm");
        }
```

This is the html file im working on: https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=EB1C71C44C3976D5!318&authkey=!AKxxwSboig3BQpo

When im using a breakpoint and watching on the List test after the work is done i see 154 links but i dont see for example this links that are in the html file content:

"http://www.niederschlagsradar.de/images.aspx?jaar=-6&type=europa.cld&datum=201311151500&cultuur=en-GB&continent=europa","http://www.niederschlagsradar.de/images.aspx?jaar=-6&type=europa.cld&datum=201311151800&cultuur=en-GB&continent=europa"

There are many links there are 61-62 links and i dont see this links in the List test.

Second this links are between:

var images = new Array(

And in the end

);

So first step i want to get all http links from the html file.
Second i want to filter and get all the http links from the html file that are between :  var images = new Array( and 
);

Comment: Isolate the issue. Test it with only the relevant HTML, replace the URLs with `http://example.com` and show the HTML here.

Answer (score 0):

hope this work for you.This code is only for the links which are in this **var images = new Array()**

```
            List<string> test = new List<string>();
            string extractUrls = YourHtmlInText;
            extractUrls = extractUrls.Remove(0, extractUrls.IndexOf("var images = new Array(") + " var images = new Array(".Length);
            extractUrls = extractUrls.Substring(0, extractUrls.IndexOf(";")).Replace(")", "").Trim();
            string[] urls = extractUrls.Split(',');
            foreach (String url in urls)
            {
                test.Add(url.Trim().Replace("\"",""));
            }
```